# What is the difference between a hash function and a pseudorandom function?

Tags: pseudo-random-function

Read the title. I've seen in RFCs that some MAC functions are called "pseudorandom functions". What are those? How are they different than hash functions? Why can't a hash function be used instead?

Answer (score 3):

A hash function is a stateless "primitive" function: given an input of X, it always produces the same output Y, where Y is a fixed length.  A cryptographically secure hash function has some additional requirements: given output Y = hash(X), it is hard to deduce input X; given output Y = hash(X1), it is hard to find output Y = hash(X2); and that it is hard to find hash(X1) = hash(X2).

Common random number generators that are used for statistical simulations are designed to produce a statistically even distribution of bits, and a hash function may be fine for this purpose.  But a statistics simulator doesn't need have the same security needs as a CSPRNG, as it isn't being used to generate cryptographic keys used to protect secrets.  A cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator (CSPRNG) needs to output bits that are unrelated to each other, so that given output bits 0-n, plus knowledge of all internal state used to produce those output bits, it is hard to determine bit n+1.

To achieve this level of unpredictability, a CSPRNG needs a source of unpredictability, called "entropy".  Entropy is surprisingly difficult to come by inside a computer; as a computer is deterministic, it generally doesn't have an internal source of randomness.  Sources of entropy are often based on unpredictable external analog data (thermal noise on a Zener diode, radioactive decay, nanosecond timing of human inputs, etc.)  But the number of bits available are limited by the time required to collect them, so there is often not a large enough "quantity" of entropy to directly output the bits of entropy to all the clients who need random numbers.

To meet the higher demand of a modern computer system that needs lots of random numbers, the small quantity of entropy available is frequently expanded using a "cryptographic sponge" function.  This is a complex algorithm built of primitive functions that are used to collect the available entropy (called "harvesting"), gather the bits in a pool, and they then "stretch" the few bits in the pool into a larger quantity of relatively unpredictable bits.  A hash function is at the core of many of the sponge functions and can be used to expand a relatively small number of bits into a larger number of unpredictable bits, but the sponge needs extra logic in order to manage the incoming bits, to produce the queue of output bits, and to refresh itself.

Comment: I asked about [pseudorandom *functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family), not pseudorandom number generators, although your answer does does answer some future questions I was going to ask.